# Затемнение экрана кроме конкретного элемента

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

Вопрос: как затемнить всё содержимое на странице, не задев конкретный div ?

Answer (score 3):

[Смотрите примерчик](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/EvNgv/) (*клик по div-у - затемняем, клик по затемняющему слою - убираем затемнение*). Думаю, что адаптировать под свою задачу, вам не составит труда.